# Is it possible to get an example of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is it possible to get an example of two matrices $A,B\in M_4(\mathbb{R})$ both having $rank<2$ but $\det(A-\lambda B)\ne 0$ i.e it is not identically a zero polynomial. where $\lambda$ is indeterminate, I mean a variable. I want to say $(A-\lambda B)$ is of full rank matrix, assuming entries of $A-\lambda B$ is a polynomial matrix with linear polynomial.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No.  If $\operatorname{rank} A < 2$ then either $A = 0$ or $\operatorname{rank} A = 1$, and similarly for $B$.  Obviously if $A = 0$ then
$$\det(A - \lambda B) = - \lambda \det B = 0$$
since $B$ is not full-rank, and similarly if $B = 0$.

So suppose $\operatorname{rank} A = \operatorname{rank} B = 1$.  Then the image of $A$ is some one-dimensional space $\operatorname{span} \{ v\}$ and the image of $B$ is some one-dimensional space $\operatorname{span} \{ w\}$.  It follows that for any $u \in \mathbb{R}^4$
$$(A - \lambda B) u = A u - \lambda B u = c v + d w \in \operatorname{span}\{v,w\}$$
for some $c, d$.  In particular, $\operatorname{rank} (A - \lambda B)$ is at most two, and thus $\det (A - \lambda B)$ is always zero.

---

If you meant to say $\operatorname{rank} A \leq 2$ and $\operatorname{rank} B \leq 2$ instead, then the answer is yes; just take
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\ 
& 1 \\ 
& & 0 \\
& & & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \qquad B = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\ 
& 0 \\ 
& & 1 \\
& & & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
for instance.  In fact, any random pair of rank-two matrices will have this property with 100% probability.

Comment: how is there a 100% probability? What if I end up with 2 matrices like A above? Then $A - \lambda B$ has rank at most 2

Comment: @RSerrao: As it turns out, only 0% of matrices have that property.  (For finite sets, 0% = impossible, but this is not the case for infinite sets.)

Comment: Believe it or not, but the actual technical term for it is that in the space of 4 by 4 matrices, this property holds "almost everywhere"

Comment: What if my random distribution is $\gamma A$ for some fixed rank-2 matrix $A$?  Each is a rank-2 matrix, they are a set of random rank-2 matrixes (so each is a random rank-2 matrix), yet it has this property with 0% probability.  ;)  (I kid, I kid)

Comment: $A-\lambda E=\pmatrix{1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0}-\lambda \pmatrix{0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1}$

Answer (score 6):

Note that $rank\ A, B < 2$ means their ranks are 1 (If any of them is 0 your question has a trivial answer). That means that all columns of $A$ are $v, \alpha_v v, \beta_v v, \delta_v v$ and the columns of $B$ are $u, \alpha_u u, \beta_u u, \delta_u u$. Now note that the columns of $(A - \lambda B)$ will be sums of those multiples of $u$ with multiples of $v$. Regardless of how you distribute the $v, \alpha_v v, \beta_v v, \delta_v v$ with the $u, \alpha_u u, \beta_u u, \delta_u u$, all columns of $(A - \lambda B)$ will be of the form $xu + yv$ for some $x$ and $y$ scalars. Therefore, all your 4 columns will be a linear combination of the two vectors $u$ and $v$ and therefore the rank of $(A - \lambda B)$ can never be greater than 2.